# wxSplitterWindow.splitVertically not accepting windows in Elixir/Erlang

Tags: elixir, wxerlang

I'm trying to get split windows working using WxErlang in Elixir.

I'm basically doing the exact same thing as the splitterWindow example from :wx.demo, but the :wxSplitterWindow.splitVertically function is returning false (not working) and I don't know wny.

Here's the code:

```
defmodule SplitWindow do

import Bitwise

import :wx_const  # A custom Erlang module that imports wx constants

def start do
    wx = :wx.new
    window = :wxFrame.new(wx, wxID_ANY, 'SplitWindow')
    :wxFrame.center(window)

    panel = :wxPanel.new(window)

    sizer = :wxBoxSizer.new(wxVERTICAL)

    splitter = :wxSplitterWindow.new(panel)

    text_edit = :wxTextCtrl.new(panel, wxID_ANY, value: 'Text Box',
        style: wxDEFAULT ||| wxTE_MULTILINE)

    text_edit2 = :wxTextCtrl.new(panel, wxID_ANY, value: 'Text Box2',
        style: wxDEFAULT ||| wxTE_MULTILINE)

    ##### This line below is where it fails #####
    IO.puts :wxSplitterWindow.splitVertically(splitter, text_edit, text_edit2)

    :wxSplitterWindow.setSashGravity(splitter, 0.5)
    :wxSplitterWindow.setMinimumPaneSize(splitter, 50)

    :wxSizer.add(sizer, splitter, flag: wxEXPAND, proportion: 1)

    :wxPanel.setSizer(panel, sizer)

    :wxFrame.show(window)
end
end
```

The IO.puts will output: false

I'm not getting any other errors.

Here is a screenshot of the program running: http://screencast.com/t/g0sG89ECi

Anyone have any ideas of what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: According to the docs, they say it returns false if it is already split: http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8.9/wx_wxsplitterwindow.html#wxsplitterwindowsplitvertically . Given that you are trying to split an splitterWindow "object", maybe the splitterWindow is actually already split and you just need to embed both its parts?

Comment: Nope, because you need to use splitVertically(), or splitHorizontally() to initialize the split (according to the docs).  But just to make sure, I used the isSplit() function before it, and it also returns false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know anything about wxWidgets, but tried your example locally (OS X) and it was breaking for me as well.

Looking at the code, on a hunch I tried setting the parent for both edit controls to be the splitter, rather than the panel, and that fixed it for me:

```
text_edit = :wxTextCtrl.new(splitter, -1, value: 'Text Box', style: 70 ||| 32)

text_edit2 = :wxTextCtrl.new(splitter, -1, value: 'Text Box2', style: 70 ||| 32)
```

Comment: Thanks that did it, the :wx.demo had that too, can't believe I didn't see it.